# Call to undefined relationship [topic] on model [App\Theme]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to display the latest Topic that is related to a Theme. I did this before and I tried the following code in the ThemesController (Index method, Sinse it's the homepage),

```
$topics = Theme::with('topic', 'lastTopic.user')->get();
$themes = Theme::all();

return view('themes.index')->with('themes', $themes)->with('topics', $topics);
```

And the method I'm calling is this.

```
public function lastTopic()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Topic::class)->latest();
}
```

The method sits inside the Theme Model, It doesn't matter if i put the method in the Topic Model of the Theme Model, It still gives me the same error. So what is causing this issue? This is for my homepage so the route is this `Route::get('/', 'ThemesController@index')->name('home');`. I know it is something I've done before but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `topic` method in your `Theme` model (if you haven't already did).

Something like:

```
public function topic()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Topic::class);
}
```

Comment: I had it already but it was named Topics. It is fixed now Thanks

Comment: Well, it doesn't work. I'm sorry but it gives me an error which states Trying to get property of non-object when I try to use the method in the view.